# AMA – Ask me anything! What type of guests would you like to see?

Tags: discussion

Some of you may have witnessed that we are planning to start hosting AMAs on GD.SE. Inspired from reddit, AMAs are basically interviews taking place between a (verified) guest and a community.

My post will be straight to the point: who would you like to have on an AMA here? I’m not necessarily looking for specific names obviously, but some more or less broad categories that you may be curious about and that may spark interesting questions. I’ll add a few of my own soon just to get things started. Obviously, there is no guarantee that we will be able to accomodate all suggestions but it's a first step.

***We are looking forward to hear about what makes you tick!***

Answer (score 7):

Data visualisation artists and graph illustrators

Answer (score 6):

Calligraphy artists and type designers

Answer (score 6):

Video game designers and artists

Comment: As long as this includes 'pixel artists', you have my upvote! Also if it doesn't ;)

Answer (score 6):

Signage and Environmental Graphic Designers

Answer (score 6):

Web Developers that implement graphic designs

Comment: I know from experience that sometimes graphic designers come up with designs that look amazing but are hard or near impossible to implement. It'd be interesting if we could pin down what to avoid when designing for web.

Comment: Designers should never avoid things. The Developers need to figure out a way to make it a reality.

Comment: @Ryan the ultimate goal in business is profit; the designers need to deliver implementable (profitable) designs. If it's going to take 3 times as long to do something that doesn't add tangible value but *looks a bit nicer* then they're not very good for business. There's a limit to how much a nice/cool/awesome design can benefit a business.

Answer (score 5):

Graphic designers turned UX designers

Answer (score 5):

Graphic design professors and historians

Answer (score 4):

Graphic designers from the packaging and labeling industry

Answer (score 3):

Logo, logotype and icon design artists

Answer (score 0):

Illustrators working with (mostly) traditional, non-digital mediums